# Fill null values with values from a column in another dataset

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 datasets like this:

```
df1.head(5)
 category cost
0   1   33.0
1   1   33.0
2   2   18.0
3   1   NaN
4   3   8.0
5   2   NaN

df2.head(2)
 cost
3 33.0
5 55.0
```

df2 contains one column with values on the same indexes, where df1 is null

I would like to do get this result:

```
df1.head(5)
 category cost
0   1   33.0
1   1   33.0
2   2   18.0
3   1   33.0
4   3   8.0
5   2   55.0
```

So fill the cost column in df1 by values in df2 on the same indexes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html)

Pandas assigns by index naturally:

```
df1['cost'] = df1['cost'].fillna(df2['cost'])

print(df1)

   category  cost
0         1  33.0
1         1  33.0
2         2  18.0
3         1  33.0
4         3   8.0
5         2  55.0
```

Comment: thank you, I was trying something similar with `df1['cost'].loc[df1['cost'].isnull()]` which didn't work

Comment: @adamlowlife, Yeh I think taking advantage of `fillna` is cleanest here.